# Detect when date contains time

Tags: swift, nsdatadetector

I'm working with NSDataDecetor in UITextView. NSDataDecetor detects date and it works correctly. But I don't know how to check when date contains time, because if text doesn't specific time (e.g. at 5PM), NSDataDecetor will set time for 12AM. Here's my code:

```
            let types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType = [.date]
            let detector = try NSDataDetector.init(types: types.rawValue)
            
            let range = NSRange(text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, in: text)

            detector.enumerateMatches(in: text, options: [], range: range) { result, flags, _ in
                addDueDateToList(range: result!.range, date: result!.date! as NSDate, hasTime: ??)
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate). NSDate *always* has time, it's always 12 AM from its default initializer, unless you tell otherwise.

Comment: You could use the Calendar function startOfDay(for:) to create a date with time set to midnight from your date and if the result and your date are equal then you, most likely, do not have time set in your date.

Comment: @HunterLion, Of course, but NSDataDetector has to know when set a default date (12PM) or set time from the text.